# jQuery monitoring form field created by AJAX query

Tags: ajax, jquery

Preface:  I am sure this is incredibly simple, but I have searched this site & the jQuery site and can't figure out the right search term to get an answer - please excuse my ignorance!

I am adding additional form fields using jQuery's ajax function and need to then apply additional ajax functions to those fields but can't seem to get jQuery to monitor these on the fly form fields.

How can I get jQuery to use these new fields?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#formField').hide();
   $('.lnk').click(function() {
      var t = this.id;
      $('#formField').show(400);
      $('#form').load('loader.php?val=' + t);
   });

      //This works fine if the field is already present
      var name  = $('#name');
      var email = $('#email');
      $('#uid').keyup(function () {
         var t = this; 
         if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
            if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);             
            this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
               $.ajax({
                  url: 'loader.php',
                  data: 'action=getUser&uid=' + t.value,         
                  type: 'get',
                  success: function (j) {
                     va = j.split("|");
                     displayname  = va[1];
                     mail         = va[2];
                     name.val(displayname);
                     email.val(mail);
                  }
               });
            }, 200);  
            this.lastValue = this.value;
         }
      });
});
```

So if the  is present in the basic html page the function works, but if it arrives by the $.load function it doesn't - presumably because $(document).ready has already started.

I did try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#formField').hide();
   $('.lnk').click(function() {
      var t = this.id;
      $('#formField').show(400);
      $('#form').load('loader.php?val=' + t);
      prepUid();
   });
});

function prepUid(){
      var name  = $('#name');
      var email = $('#email');
     $('#uid').keyup(function () {
snip...........
```

But it didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are close. You need to add your keyup handler once the .load call is complete. Try changing this...

```
  $('#form').load('loader.php?val=' + t);
  prepUid();
```

To this...

```
  $('#form').load('loader.php?val=' + t, null, prepUid);
```

Comment: I think this solution works. Ive used it many times with the older jquery versions before the live() function.  With the live() function you dont need to worry about order and it helps keep things separate.  Just a thought...

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something. In the code, a click handler is added to elements with the .lnk class. Are there .lnk elements being added to the DOM through these AJAX requests? If so, you definitely want to use .live() for those elements. You could also use .live("keyup", ...) for the input fields. I personally tend to avoid using .live() unless its absolutely necessary. Just me...

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the jquery live function.

> *Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future*

You can do something like this:

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {// Live handler called.});
```

and then add something using the DOM

```
$('body').append('<div class="clickme">Another target</div>');
```

When you click the div added above it will trigger the click handler as you expect with statically loaded dom nodes.

You can read more  here: http://api.jquery.com/live/